# Help building table

Tags: tables, color

I would like to make this kind of table in a Latex editor. My problem, in particular, is to merge columns and rows to make the title and the Dimension 1 and 2 legends. Can you help me?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure it can fit the width of a standard paper sheet. Maybe you'll have to use a rotated table. For the titles , use `\multicolumn{15}{c}{\bfseries Title}` and `\multicolumn{14}{c}{\bfseries Dimension 1}`.

Comment: How can I write it vertically? I would use it in appendix

Comment: The `rotating` package defines a  `sidewaystable` environment. Other possibility: the `lscape` package defines a `` landscape` environment.

Comment: Let me add that, to have a better looking table, I would use the `siunitx` package and its `S` column type to align the numbers in the white part on the decimal comma.

Comment: Do you actually need 6 digits after the decimal markers? Would anything get lost if you asked LaTeX to show just 3 digits, say?

Comment: If you don't want to struggle too much, you can even use [LaTeX Tables](https://www.latex-tables.com/) to make your table using the UI interface then export in in LaTeX. By watching the generated code you understand how it works. Packages used to rotate and merge cells here are `makecell` and `multirow`.

Answer (score 2):

With new package `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}\tiny
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={|X[c]|*{15}{X[r]|}},
    cell{1}{1}={r=1,c=16}{c},
    cell{2-16}{1}={cyan},
    cell{2-16}{2}={cyan},
    cell{4}{1}={r=13,c=1}{c, cyan},
    cell{2}{3}={r=1,c=14}{c, cyan},
    hlines
    }
Title&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&Dimension 1&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
&&1.4&1.5&1.6&1.7&1.8&1.9&2&2.1&2.2&2.3&2.4&2.5&2.6&2.7\\
{D\\ i\\ m\\ e\\ n\\s \\i\\o\\n\\~ \\2}&1&1.411111&1.511111&1.611111&1.711111&1.811111&1.911111&2.111111&2.111111&2.211111&2.311111&2.411111&2.511111&2.611111&2.711111\\
&2&1.411111&1.511111&1.611111&1.711111&1.811111&1.911111&2.111111&2.111111&2.211111&2.311111&2.411111&2.511111&2.611111&2.711111\\
&3&1.411111&1.511111&1.611111&1.711111&1.811111&1.911111&2.111111&2.111111&2.211111&2.311111&2.411111&2.511111&2.611111&2.711111\\
&1&1.411111&1.511111&1.611111&1.711111&1.811111&1.911111&2.111111&2.111111&2.211111&2.311111&2.411111&2.511111&2.611111&2.711111\\
&1&1.411111&1.511111&1.611111&1.711111&1.811111&1.911111&2.111111&2.111111&2.211111&2.311111&2.411111&2.511111&2.611111&2.711111\\
&1&1.411111&1.511111&1.611111&1.711111&1.811111&1.911111&2.111111&2.111111&2.211111&2.311111&2.411111&2.511111&2.611111&2.711111\\
&1&1.411111&1.511111&1.611111&1.711111&1.811111&1.911111&2.111111&2.111111&2.211111&2.311111&2.411111&2.511111&2.611111&2.711111\\
&1&1.411111&1.511111&1.611111&1.711111&1.811111&1.911111&2.111111&2.111111&2.211111&2.311111&2.411111&2.511111&2.611111&2.711111\\
&1&1.411111&1.511111&1.611111&1.711111&1.811111&1.911111&2.111111&2.111111&2.211111&2.311111&2.411111&2.511111&2.611111&2.711111\\
&1&1.411111&1.511111&1.611111&1.711111&1.811111&1.911111&2.111111&2.111111&2.211111&2.311111&2.411111&2.511111&2.611111&2.711111\\
&1&1.411111&1.511111&1.611111&1.711111&1.811111&1.911111&2.111111&2.111111&2.211111&2.311111&2.411111&2.511111&2.611111&2.711111\\
&1&1.411111&1.511111&1.611111&1.711111&1.811111&1.911111&2.111111&2.111111&2.211111&2.311111&2.411111&2.511111&2.611111&2.711111\\
&1&1.411111&1.511111&1.611111&1.711111&1.811111&1.911111&2.111111&2.111111&2.211111&2.311111&2.411111&2.511111&2.611111&2.711111\\
\end{tblr}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: my new favorite package

Comment: @JeT Indeed, it's great! I'm answering these just-do-it-for-me questions just to familiarize myself with it.

Comment: I think you can factorize the \hline. checking it out.

Comment: @JeT Done, really great! Thank you!